# Correct Use of Get/Got

Tags: sentence-construction

How we will come to know that he got the documents?

Or

How we will come to know that he gets the documents?

Which one is grammatically correct?

Scenario.

I will have to take action after receiving document by xyz. So I want to say How "We will come to know that he got/get the document so that we can proceed further."

Answer (score 1):

You need to say "How will we" when asking a question.

I would use "got" here:

> How will we come to know that he got the documents?

or even better

> How will we know that he got the documents?

On the other hand, if you were using "when" instead of "that" you would use present or present perfect tense:

> How will we know when he gets the documents?
>
> How will we know when he's gotten the documents?
>
> How will we know when he's obtained the documents?

Comment: Why Past Tense "Got" for future Tense/event?

Comment: Why Past Tense "Got" for future Tense/event?

Comment: As a native speaker, I can tell you what sounds right or wrong.  But, I couldn't find any reference material explaining the general rule here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the verb **receive** rather than **get**, because in some contexts get may have the sense of the person actively fetching something rather than the sense of receiving.

I recommend using a simple past tense:

> How we will come to know that he received the documents.

The key idea is that we want to know that the documents are now in his possession, they were received some time previously.

> How we will come to know that he gets the documents.

is valid and idiomatic, and does imply delivery of the documents to the recipient. I see "get" as less formal in a business context.

Comment: I have added context. Please edit your answer